# in order to [gerund] or [infinitive]?

Tags: prepositions, infinitives, gerunds, in-order-to

There are few questions and answer on the choice of gerund versus infinitive.
From what I understand, when conveying a purpose the infinitive should be used:

> I use my key in order to open the door. [correct]
>   I use my key in order to opening the door. [incorrect]
>   I use words to describe my dream. [correct]
>   I use words to describing my dream. [incorrect]

Yet I read the instruction on an English lesson book:

> "Use similes to describing the animals here below."

Could you please confirm what should follow "(in order) to": the gerund or the infinitive?

Comment: "Use similes **for** describing the animals (here) below."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a mistake. It should be *Use similes **to describe** the animals here below.* You might want to get a different book.

Comment: It's a handbook designed for children by an English native speaker. I'm supposed to take over her task, so I'll edit accordingly. The fact a native speaker chose to use a gerund made me hesitate. Thanks.

Comment: And it's not really necessary to say _here below_. _Below_ is enough. Or simply _these animals_.

Comment: Not only is it not necessary, it sounds rather odd.

Comment: Maybe it was "use similes in describing the animals here [or: below]" and got mangled during copy-editing to be what you now see.